# Redis+Django cause a servor error (500) with ubuntu 18.04 on a cloud server

Tags: django, redis, digital-ocean

I tried to install Redis on Django in a Digitalocean droplet following this guide : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-redis-from-source-on-ubuntu-18-04 and this other guide before : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-redis-on-ubuntu-18-04.

I can use redis via the console with redis-cli, but on each web page a redis command there is an error 500.

In views.py :

```
# Redis
import redis
from django.conf import settings

# Connect to Redis
r = redis.StrictRedis (
    host = 'localhost',
    port = 6379,
    db = 0)
```

I don't know at all what is the source of this problem.

Comment: Please show the full traceback from the yellow debug page/your logs/the error email sent to the site admins.

Comment: did you do `pip install redis` ?

Comment: I do not receive a log via email. I have probably not fill my email at some point during the install.

Comment: When I do pip install redis :
Requirement already satisfied: redis in /home/name/KOM/my_site_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages

Comment: Focus on setting up logging/error emails ([docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/error-reporting/). If you only see `500 server error`, then you can only guess what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

After the excellent advice from Alasdair to set up log/error emails the problem was easy to fix.

The error message was:
AttributeError at /thebuggedpage/ **‘Redis’ object has no attribute ‘HGETALL’**

First I tried :

```
pip install --upgrade redis django-redis-cache django-redis-sessions
```

but the console was unhappy and answered me this :

```
Failed building wheel for django-redis-cache (...)
error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
----------------------------------------
Failed building wheel for django-redis-sessions
```

So I did that:
pip install wheel

then again:

```
pip install --upgrade redis django-redis-cache django-redis-sessions
```

And after the console was happy again :)

And finally I changed HGETALL for hgetall.

My apologies to non-professionals for the use of some very high level technical terms such as unhappy console.
An unhappy console is when she writes things in red. There you go.